# Voting on website

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want people to be able to vote "yes" or "no" on an area of my website. I have my form submission entered into mysql.

Now I want to add an area where they can vote and each vote changes the number.

So say this the database has 4 areas 
`topic - comments my name - id (auto_increment)`. I added this to it `voteY` and `VoteN`

If they click on the Thumb Up it changes the value of VoteY in the database to 1 and then another user clicks it and it changes to 2 and so on and so forth. The thumbs down is the same exact way but it has to work with this code. I have and I'm not sure if it is possible. If it is, what would I search for on google? The site bugmenot.com has the voting for topics and its linked to there database but I can't figure it out. Here's my script.

```
<?php require "manybr.htm" ?>
<style>
<?php require "styles.css" ?>
</style>
<?php
    $host="host"; // Host name 
    $username="user"; // Mysql username 
    $password="pass"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="database"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="Users"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // select record from mysql 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table background='images/view.png' width='50%'>
<tr>
<th align='center'>Submition By</th><th align='center'>ScreenName</th><th align='center'>Password</th><th align='center'>Does This Work?</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
    </th>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
    </th>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
    </th>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
    </th>
</tr>
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>

<tr>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['yname']; ?> </b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['username']; ?></b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['password']; ?></b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['works']; ?>% Yes <font color='transparent'>||||</font>&nbsp; 
    <? echo $rows['dworks']; ?>% No</b></i></td>
</tr>

<?php } // close while loop  ?>

</table>

<?php mysql_close(); // close connection;  ?>
<center>
```

I know I should use `MySQLi` or `PDO` but I have not learned that yet.

Comment: I think not many people are going to read that unless you use some punctuation.

Comment: If you aren't using MYSQLI or PDO and insist on using MYSQL, you will still need to write to the database with an `INSERT` query.

Comment: Please edit your question title to something that will be meaningful in a search in the future. "I'm not sure how to find the answer so im going to ask" is not a useful search phrase, and it doesn't give anyone any indication of what your question is about. While you're at it, you can break up the big wall of text at the top by inserting some paragraph breaks and punctuation so that it's actually readable. :-) If it's hard to read or understand, people won't bother to read it, and you won't get help as quickly. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the title name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is that you wanna change the value of `voteY` and `VoteN` after a user clicked on `YES` or `NO`?

**If this is your question you can do something like:**

```
    <?php

    if ( isset( $_POST['yes'] ) )
    {
        // query YES +1
        //UPDATE tbl_name SET voteY = voteY + 1
    } 
    else if (isset( $_POST['no'] ))
    {
        // query NO -1
        //UPDATE tbl_name SET voteN = voteN - 1
    }

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="yes" name="yes">
    <input type="submit" value="no" name="no">
</form>
```

Comment: i want ti to change the value of the number in the database

Comment: @user1929322 yes, you need to do a UPDATE QUERY `UPDATE tbl_name SET voteN = voteN - 1`

Comment: it dosent work i made a new question about it with alot more details and i fixed some things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049168/update-problems-with-creating-simple-php-mysql-voting-system